# byte ToString without converting from hexidecimal

Tags: c#, string, byte, hex

I am using c# to read information coming out of a scale and I am getting back 6 bytes of Data. The last two contain the weight, in Hexadecimal. The way that it is set up is that if your append byte 5 on to byte 4 and convert to decimal you will get the correct weight.

I am trying to do this right now by using toString on the bytes and appending them but toString is automatically converting them from Hexadecimal to decimal. This is occurring before I can append them so I am getting incorrect weights.

Is there any way to convert a byte to a string without it being formatted from hexadecimal to decimal for you?

Comment: Please show us an example of the “6 bytes” you are getting, and what you are doing now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `X` format string when calling `ToString` on your bytes to keep them in hexadecimal. You can append a number to `X` to specify the number of "digits" you want.

```
byte b = 0x0A;
b.ToString("X"); // A
b.ToString("X2"); // 0A
```